# Correct name for "Loading" effect

Tags: refresh

i dont know if this is the right place to ask this, but it seems right...
A bit of context first: In my old job i was lead by a senior consultant that kept talking about the "need" of the user to see a "loading-indicator". What he was talking about is not a application "freezing" because the main thread was blocked by a long-running operation, but about the "need" of some users to see something new, and if nothing new happened, the user would hit F5...

That being said here is my question: What is the general-accepted-name for this "fenomenon"?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_indicator , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber ,
http://www.googlefight.com/index.phplang=en_GB&word1=progress+indicator&word2=loading+indicator ,
http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=progress+indicator&word2=busy+indicator ,
http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=throbber&word2=spinner

Comment: @user2864740 i dont need a the name of the thing that appears... pls read the question...

Comment: *"Correct name for “Loading” effect"*

Answer (score 0):

The words [progress indicator](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/progress-indicator/) come to mind

Comment: It's not necessarily progress, just "the computer is busy doing *something*, so wait".

Comment: A more generic term is 'feedback'. But if the computer is doing something then it must be making progress in some way, surely? Progress bars, 'throbbers', spinning clocks and egg timer icons can all be categorized as progress indicators.

Comment: From the link: "a display showing *how far* a time-consuming process has gone". A "throbber" or "spinner" or "timer" goes and goes and goes .. the actual progress (or lack of) is not being indicated.

Comment: (Note that while I quoted from the link provided, partly to make a point, Wikipedia and other definition do not include "how far" wording.)

Comment: Neither does this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgIndic/Concepts/AboutProgIndic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000111-BCIECBIG

Comment: But I still do not consider a "progress [bar] indicator" to fulfill the same roles as a "progress [loading] indicator".

Comment: Me neither. But I'm glad you agree they can both be called "progress indicators" :-)